# How to sort HashMap as added in Android with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, hashmap, android-spinner

I have a `HashMap<String,String>` and there is a static method which returns this map to an `Activity`.

Method looks like this:

```java
public static HashMap<String, String> getAll() {    
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    map.put("ab", "value1");
    map.put("bc", "value2");
    map.put("de", "value3");

    return map;
}
```

I want to use that map with a spinner. So activity looks like this:

```java
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, String> map = Constants.getAll();

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    list.add(Constants.getAll().get(key).toString());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinTest = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinTest);

spinTest.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        urlDebug.setText(list.get(arg2).toString());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});

spinTest.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I tried to run my application, no problem at all. But when I clicked on spinner, items not ordered as I added on getAll() method. I mean, order has to be ab - bc -de but it's ordered randomly.

What's not true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in hashmap, insertion order is not maintained, so item inserted last may accessed first. If you want to maintain order of insertion, use linkedhashmap instead.

Comment: Or, just use a TreeMap. It's what it's there for you know.

Comment: You just saved my hours!

Answer (score 2):

**Update : Answer by jitendra sharma is the best : 
A treemap costs a lot more than a linkedhashmap and adds nothing to your project if you only need to keep original insertion order.**

Hashmap cannot get sorted. That's part of their efficiency.

If you need sorting, then use a [TreeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Good luck.

Comment: A TreeMap is not especially inefficient for a normal number of items - considering the fact that there's apparently few items enough to use a spinner.

Comment: I just added the update to be sure futur reader know what to expect and for good practices. From the Oracle Java doc : "This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by HashMap (and Hashtable), without incurring the increased cost associated with TreeMap" : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You should either call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or spinTest.setAdapter(adapter) after you sorted your list.

```
spinTest.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        urlDebug.setText(list.get(arg2).toString());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});

spinTest.setAdapter(adapter);
// TODO: Sort the list
// Some code here
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```